# rich:suggestionbox error - this.element is null

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying use `rich:suggestionbox`. I went through the tutorial provided by the Richfaces. The important thing is that I am using Richfaces 3.1.4 JAR. In the suggestion box, I am just trying to populate some default data at the starting, but the suggestion box is not rendering at all. When I try to see the error console in Firefox, the following error message is shown:

`Error: this.element is null
Source File: http://localhost:9080/sample/a4j_3_1_4.GAorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/suggestionbox.js.faces
Line: 2`

**JSF CODE**

```
<a4j:region selfRendered="true" id="region1">
    <h:inputText id="fx" />
    <rich:suggestionbox width="50" height="50" for="fx" nothingLabel="HI"
        suggestionAction="#{basic.inputData}" fetchValue="#{basic.selectedData}"
        var="result" id="suggestion">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{result.value}" />
        </h:column>
    </rich:suggestionbox>
    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="show data"
        action="#{basic.submit}"></h:commandButton>
</a4j:region>
```

**MANAGED BEAN**

```
enter code here
    private List<SelectedList> inputData; // Setter
    private String selectedData;   // Getter and Setter

    public List<SelectedList> getInputData() {          //Getter
    if(inputData!=null){
        inputData = new ArrayList<SelectedList>();
        inputData.add(new SelectedList("1","equal"));
        inputData.add(new SelectedList("2","not equal"));
        inputData.add(new SelectedList("3","greater"));
        inputData.add(new SelectedList("4","lesser"));
    }
    return inputData;
}
```

Kindly help, if you please.

Comment: which jsf version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**:after changing your code:

change the method `inputData` like this:

(Of course, I believe that you need to adjust the inputdata according the the suggest string..)

```
public List<Capital> inputData(Object suggest) {
        String pref = (String)suggest;
        //if (suggest...) - add this! to complete according the word
        ArrayList<SelectedList> inputData = new ArrayList<SelectedList>();

        inputData.add(new SelectedList("1","equal"));
        inputData.add(new SelectedList("2","not equal"));
        inputData.add(new SelectedList("3","greater"));
        inputData.add(new SelectedList("4","lesser"));

        return inputData;
    }
```

and for:

```
fetchValue="#{basic.selectedData}"
```

You need to change it to: `fetchValue="#{result.value}"` where value is has a getter method in `SelectedList`.

If you are missing it, it will not be displayed..

See an example of [Suggestion Box Demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/suggestionBox.jsf)

Comment: Sorry it was a typo error instead of inputData i ha typed as populate in the JSF code. I have the getter and the setter method generated by default, thats the reason i have mentioned Getter and Setter in the Code itself to reduce the space.

Comment: In suggestionAction you need an action to fill the selected item.
You don't need getter and setter for it.